# Is possible to save custom datatypes like Java’s LocalDateTime into Realm (Kotlin SDK)?

Tags: java, kotlin, realm

In Kotlin Realm SDK, is there a way to define for example:

`var lcalDateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()`

in RealmObject in and add support for serialization of this class into Realm?
I see that new Kotlin SDK versions support KSerializer but thats probably not meant for this right? It would be nice if I can transform the java.time classes by some custom transformer into RealmInstant.

At this moment, I am doing it like so:

```
    @PersistedName("dayScheduled")
    private var _dayScheduled: RealmInstant = RealmInstant.now()
    var dayScheduled: LocalDate
        get() = LocalDate.from(_dayScheduled.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))
        set(value) {
            _dayScheduled = value.atStartOfDay().toRealmInstant()
        }
```

This solution works but I am seraching for something with less boilerplate.